# Node.js pipe http request through socket.io stream

Tags: node.js, socket.io, http-proxy

Im working on a project to expose private web services behind a firewall to the public internet but through a proxy that authenicates all requests.

Basically I have a public node.js process that does all the authentication, and redirects the requests to the appropriate endpoints. I'm using http-proxy to proxy the requests once I authenticate them.

Currently I have a node.js service running on all endpoints and I'm using openvpn to create the tunnel and iptables to redirect any requests that are not on localhost. The local node.js process manages adding and removing iptable rules and the authentication of the openvpn connection plus updating of the actual node.js code.

This works but is clunky and not hugely scalable.

I would like to pipe the http request from the public server through the websocket connection to the node.js process on the other side and redirect it to whatever ip:port its meant for.

**Basic Network Diagram**

[image: [1]:]

Heres a basic network of what I'm trying to accomplish.
I have tried to understand how pipes and streams would work together to accomplish this with no real success.

Can anyone provide me some basic sample code that would accomplish this?

Comment: Why not just straight-up use a normal HTTP proxy server?  Why must you have this websocket connection?

Comment: There are multiple endpoints(40 right now, hopefully 100+ soon) and the main server forwards to endpoints behind the firewall all multiple locations. Can't do this with a normal proxy

Comment: Sure you can... architecturally it's similar to what you're proposing, but without all the complexity, and without having to re-invent it.

Comment: I want to remove the openvpn tunnel tho so how else can I tunnel behind the firewall securely using a standard proxy? I also want to intercept and individually authenticate each request before allowing the proxy to make sure only the correct people access the correct endpoints. I'm currently doing this with the openvpn and http-proxy but I want to simplify it by passing the data through the websocket connection thats already open instead of through the openvpn tunnel.

Comment: You simply put your proxy (the one you're building which does all the auth, or an appropriately configured Nginx instance) in a place where it has access to your things behind the firewall, and is exposed publicly.

Comment: Yea that sounds easy but doesnt really apply in this instance. The public server is a cloud server(azure, digitalocean, heroku, etc). The endpoints all call into the public server to expose services behind them. They themselves cant have public ips. There is only one public ip server for many endpoints distributed all over the world. Currently all endpoints tunnel home over openvpn so that the http-proxy redirects can specify an ip address of the openvpn network but I would like to eliminate openvpn if possible

Comment: I should have mentioned. The left server is a single public server. The right is an example of one of many private servers.

Comment: So basically, you're taking an industry-standard simple solution to this problem, and you want to replace it with a hacked-together Socket.IO transport?  I don't see the benefit.

Comment: No not really. Can you give me an example of where I can see an industry implementation using hundreds of distributed endpoints? I don't want to remake anything from scratch but haven't found anything that does what I need

Comment: I'm running a similar system myself, albeit on Hamachi rather than OpenVPN.  (OpenVPN is fine, I just didn't want to manage my own VPN servers, and I liked the distributed nature of the way Hamachi worked.)  I call that my "management" network, as it was originally just for SSH and such, but I run back-end APIs over it.  There are a few servers that have a public IP endpoint (my Node.js server which handles request authentication), as well as access to the management network (to get the data to serve those requests).  It works reasonably well.

Comment: In your case, depending on your auth needs, you could just use something like Nginx as-is.  If you need fancier handling of your APIs, you can use Node.js or similar.  But, use the proxy module.  Don't proxy data over a WebSocket connection... you can use your VPN as that backhaul connection.  The VPN is going to give you the access you need without having to build a proprietary connection, while helping with security.

Comment: Thanks for your insite brad. I am attempting to make the endpoint setup completely painless. Maybe I will stick with what I am currently using but put some effort into passing the certificates through the socket connection to make the management easier.

Comment: Is the issue with configuring all the OpenVPN stuff?  What do you mean when you say you want to pass certificates through a socket?

Comment: I want it to be free of configuration for the endpoints. Currently I would have to pass things(usernames,passwords,config files, certificates) to the endpoints to make the openvpn connection. I'm looking to simplify that, i may try this some more https://github.com/ericbarch/socket-tunnel I did breifly try this but didn't get too far yet

Comment: They have to be on a network accessible to your proxy... what you're proposing to do doesn't change that.

Comment: It does because all the endpoints call home and create a socket.io connection. If the request can go over that socket backwards to the endpoint network than it doesn't have to be accessible to the network at all. The socket-tunnel I mentioned i had played with previously but chose against it for latency but I just did some testing and the latency is close enough to satisfy my needs.  By going that route without openvpn it greatly simplifies deployment and scaling. I think I have the basic working model I need from that project. Thanks for letting me talk this through with you.

Comment: Just finished some proof of concept testing with https://github.com/ericbarch/socket-tunnel with load testing from all over and surprisingly it actually outperformed nginx in most tests when run from the same machine. By those tests it should far outperform the overhead of openvpn.